# how to get xml files from shared directory

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to get files list from shared directory, under this directory there is subdirectories with the names of the person who logged in to the application, so for that i have to get automatically files according to this person 
ex: shared directory Clients sub directory : Client1 (when he log in he gets a file's list located under the subdirectory Client1 )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Using System.IO;
String xmlPathName = Path.Combine(basePath, "Client1");
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(xmlPathName);
if (di.Exists)
{
    foreach(FileInfo file in di.GetFiles("*.xml")
    {
        String fileName  = file.Name;
        String fileFullName  = file.FullName;
        //add some code for each file ...
    }
}
```